# Is Goodstein's theorem equivalent to $\varepsilon_0$-induction over weak base theories (e.g. PRA)?

Tags: logic, proof-theory, ordinal-analysis

Is Goodstein's theorem equivalent to $\varepsilon_0$-induction over a weak base theory like [**PRA**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_arithmetic)? I'm surprised this hasn't been asked here before (as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 4):

Rathjen proved that the Goodstein theorem proves $\mathsf{PRWO}$, which states that there is no decreasing primitive recursive sequence of ordinals $<\epsilon_0$, over $\mathsf{PRA}$. You may refer the following article for the proof:

> Rathjen, Michael. "Goodstein’s theorem revisited." in *Gentzen's Centenary: The Quest for Consistency*. Springer, Cham, 2015. 229-242.

On the other hand, we can encode the standard proof of the Goodstein theorem by using $\mathsf{PRWO}$ and Cantor normal form of ordinals $<\epsilon_0$:
Every Goodstein sequence yields a computable sequence of decreasing ordinals. In fact, it is primitive recursive - we know how to compute the Goodstein sequence by using bounded loops. Thus if there is a counterexample of Goodstein's theorem, then $\mathsf{PRWO}$ fails.

I do not know $\mathsf{PRWO}$ is equivalent to $\epsilon_0$-induction (at least for primitive recursive relations), though.

---

(Added in 23 April 2021) I found that [Arai's textbook](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9789811564581) stated the following theorem (Theorem 4.1(e) of his textbook):

> **Theorem.** $\mathsf{I\Sigma_1}$ proves $\mathsf{PRWO}$ is equivalent to the 1-consistency of $\mathsf{PA}$.

Arai stated this theorem under different terminology. He uses $\mathscr{E}^\omega DS_{\epsilon_0}$ for $\mathsf{PRWO}$.
Also, his original statement is more general than I mentioned. Note, however, that $\mathsf{I\Sigma_1}$ is stronger than $\mathsf{PRA}$.

Comment: Ok, thanks, this is interesting! Some initial questions: 1) how do you express PRWO in the language of PRA? I don't have a lot of experience working in PRA, but I know it doesn't have quantifiers (save for implicit universals) and my first intuition is that PRWO is $\Pi_2$. How does that work? 2) PRWO proves Con(PA) over PA, does it also over PRA?

Comment: So you say that over PRA, PRWO and Goodstein are equivalent. However you do not know how PRWO relates to $\epsilon_0$-induction. Is that correct?

Comment: @Jori I do not know the meaning of 'PRA has no quantifier.' PRA is a first-order theory, and first-order logic has universal and existential quantifiers. You could mean that *PRA does not have an induction scheme for quantified statements*, but it has no relation with the expressibility of $\mathsf{PRWO}$.

Comment: @Jori For the second and third questions, yes. Gentzen's proof still works (according to Rathjen; I have not checked the detail of the Gentzen's proof yet.)

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_arithmetic: "Primitive recursive arithmetic (PRA) is a quantifier-free formalization of the natural numbers". I know it can be formulated with quantifiers, but I don't know exactly how.

Comment: @Jori This description does not mean every formula of PRA does not have quantifiers. It could mean every axiom has no unbounded quantifiers (except for some universal quantifiers that can be implicit.)

Comment: @Jori Also, Wikipedia already gives how to formulate the axioms of PRA without any quantifiers.